# Subscribe for certain tags in review queue

Tags: feature-request, review

In its current form the review queue is quite useless. There some random people meet random questions on the topics they have no clue about. As a result, in its current form, the review queue is good only for grammar issues, or even harmful, when people tend to vote randomly when they have no idea how to vote at all.

Personally, I feel very uneasy when I get into the queue on occasion. Thinking "what are all these questions? Who are all these people? What do I have to do with them?" I am just trying to get out as fast as possible.

I am somewhat a narrow specialist, I have great knowledge in some areas, but even in my own language I am not a pro in everything. So, unlike most folks here, I want to participate only in the areas I can be useful and effective. This applies to the review queue as well.

Thus, such a feature would be nice to implement: **a tag subscription for the review queue**.

Say, having some proven expertise for a certain tag (e.g. a silver badge), I am being able to subscribe for the review queue for this tag. From now on I will be a willing participant in a review process.

A step in the privileges ladder would be also nice to add, for advertising purposes - to let people know that they now can use this feature.

By implementing this feature, the network would profit from two main benefits:

1. Put a lot more people in a review process.
2. **At last make the review process relevant and professional.**

P.S. Some weight for the vote from a pro would be also nice, but I quite realize it will never be implemented.

Update.
It seems it's already implemented. Then it needs to be better advertised.

Comment: If you're thinking that people will subscribe to queues without having reviewed, they will continue to be unlikely to review. The same people will be reviewing. The other feature that you propose already exists: through tag filters.

Comment: You mean suggested edits queue? Because as far as I can tell other queues got a filter by tag feature already.

Comment: Note that there is always the possibility to **skip** a review when you don't have a clue.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica imho the point is to avoid spending most of the time on skipping stuff that one has no clue of.

*Btw, could someone please please please direct me to some instruction on how to use tags* -- as it was clearly implemented ages ago and I assume is dead simple to use (why it is not automatically bound to one's top used tags then)?