# How do I narrow my review queue using tags?

Tags: support, review

A follow-up to [Subscribe for certain tags in review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262034/subscribe-for-certain-tags-in-review-queue)

I'm new to review queues, and apparently there's a way to *greatly* save one's time *(please read the linked question, I can't agree more)* by subscribing to review only those Q&A which fall into my areas of expertise. ( I suppose we'll be using StackOverflow' tags to do so. )

Can someone please enlighten me on how to do this ?

Comment: In the top left corner, next to the name of the review queue you are in there is a "filter" link.